# Prove by Induction that $\binom{n}{k}$ is always a natural number.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I have come up with the following proof.

Base Case: If n = 1, then k = 1 because n $\geq$ k , $\forall$n,k $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$.
Thus, $\binom{1}{1}$ = $\frac{1!}{1!(1-1)!} = 1 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Inductive Hypothesis: Assume that $\binom{m}{k} \in \mathbb{N}$ for some $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

Inductive Step: We are given that $\binom{m+1}{k} = \binom{m}{k-1} + \binom{m}{k}$. By assumption, we know that $\binom{m}{k} \in \mathbb{N}$, so as a result we must prove that $\binom{m}{k-1} \in \mathbb{N}$. Because the natural numbers are closed under addition, the sum of the two terms will also result in a natural number.

Hence, a bit of algebra yields $\binom{m}{k-1} = \frac{k}{m-k+1} \times \binom{m}{k}$. This is where I’m stuck. I need to show that $\frac{k}{m-k+1} \in \mathbb{N}$. From this, I can then claim that the product is then a natural number because the natural numbers are closed under multiplication.

Αny help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is: $P(n):=\text{For } n \geq 1, \binom{n}{k} \text{ is an integer for all } 0 \leq k \leq n$. So when you have the correct induction hypothesis, then you have $\binom{m}{k-1}$ is an integer.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Here’s a better inductive assumption: Assume that for some $m$ (the induction variable) the binomial coefficient $\begin{pmatrix}m\\k\end{pmatrix}$ is a natural number *for every $0 \leq k \leq m$*.

Comment: It is not just "better", it is the "correct" one that OP should be using as the statement to be proven.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thank you.